# Splitting Data before and after a certain date

Tags: r, date, split, dataframe

I have a dataframe of and I want to split it into two different data frames, one before a certain date, and one after the date. Which is the best code for this, I have tried the split code but cant seem to get it to work?

Comment: Can you share your dataframe with us? Try `dput(df[1:10, ])` where `df` is the name of the variable containing the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
df  <- data.frame(date=as.Date("2013-01-01")+1:365, x=1:365)
lst <- split(df,df$date<as.Date("2013-06-01"))
```

This will split df into 2 dataframes, one with dates prior to 2013-06-01 and one with dates subsequent. You can access the dataframes as `lst[1]` and `lst[2]`

Comment: Would this be for a data frame of 365 pieces of data?

Comment: That's just an example. The only requirement is that the column containing the dates is in date format or can be converted using, e.g.  `df$dates <- as.Date(df$dates)`.

Comment: When I try the code  **df$dates<as.Date("2001-08-11")**  It gives me the repsonse **logical(0)** Do you know what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Is `df$dates` a date or a character string? Try df$dates <- as.Date(df$dates)` and then to the split.

Comment: It gives this message: **Error in as.Date.default(df$dates) : 
  do not know how to convert 'df$dates' to class “Date”**

Comment: Also **dates$dates<as.Date("2001-08-11")** gives
**Error in dates$dates : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors**

Comment: What is `dates$dates`?? Can you just post your actual dataset? Type `dput(df)` and post the output of that as an edit to your question. Alternatively, upload your dataset and post a link.

Comment: I've managed to split the data manually now, thank you for all your help though, I really appreciate it!

Comment: A Date class object can be compared to an appropriately formatted  character class object so `df$date < as.Date("2013-06-01")` could be written `df$date < "2013-06-01"`

Answer (score 2):

Let me show you how to do this really fast and easily using `data.table`.

```
require(data.table)
my_df = data.table(a=seq.Date(from=as.Date("2012-01-01"), by=1, len=10),b=10:1)
N = as.Date("2012-01-05") #where you want to split
df1 = my_df[a<N]
df2 = my_df[a>=N]
```